# How to make window.prompt in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-js-interop

I make some apps using Dart and I have one simple question. I haven't found the prompt dialog in dart:html library. I've found only alert and confirm dialog calls, but that's not, what I need. I've tried some other possibilities from Dart api, but no way to do it. I think there should be something like a modal dialog or Dart own prompt dialog. I know, modal is here, but it only loads another file in the popup.

Can somebody help me?

---

**Update:** Actually, I found one solution. It's an emulation of JavaScript in dart:js library:

```
var password=context.callMethod('prompt',['Password','']);
```

It is good solution, but I think, that there must be something better than emulating JavaScript.

---

**Update 2:** Because of an insufficiency of the prompt dialog in the Dart spec, Dart APIs and Dart libraries **[here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15170)** is a bug on Google Code issue tracker, so let's **star** the bug, if you think prompt is important in the spec or comment if you have any other idea, how to do it in a modern way (you can try to propose something like built-in modal dialog for example). Or just share it if you think prompt/modal dialog implementation should be also in modern programming languages...

---

**Update 3:** Now we are discussing the new modal alert, confirm and prompt dialogs, which could be in Polymer.dart library. **[Here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15223)** is the enhancement on Google Code issue tracker, so let's **star** the bug, if you are for the modern modal form of that dialogs, or discuss, if you know how to do it better...

Comment: This replacement prompt() method does not need to be on the Window object. It can be implemented in a separate package.

Comment: Yes, it can. I thought, it can be affiliated to the ModalDialog package, but it can be also implemented in Polymer UI elements, or wherever else. It could be modal dialog, UI element, or its own separate unit in Dart. But it should exist in Dart, you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use js interop to do this:

```
import 'dart:js';

main() {
  var result = context.callMethod('prompt', ['Hello from Dart!']);
  print(result);
}
```

I'm not sure why this is not available in dart:html. Perhaps file a [bug](http://dartbug.com).

Ideally you'd be able to use another UI component library to do this, rather than using window.prompt(). Something like [these](http://dart-lang.github.io/widget.dart/#modal). But it's still pretty early days, and I'm not sure if there is a good library available yet.

**Update:**

window.prompt() has be purposefully removed from dart:html to discourage its use as it blocks the execution of script.

Comment: But as I wrote, I know js interop, I had found an existing bug (its statement is fixed, but nobody knows how...) and I had also found  modal in the spec, but it doesn't fit my needs...
Thank you for the modal library. I think, I'll use it instead of js interop function, if there isn't any other better and simpler way.

Comment: Window.prompt() is a bit of hack from the 90's. For example, while open, it will prevent all other javascript on the page from running. Definitely better to use something else. But I agree, sometimes when doing a quick prototype window.prompt() is useful. Filed a bug for you here - https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15170

Comment: I know. But the modal you wrote about seems to me really good. I only have to wait until its developers rewrite it into Polymer branch. I don't want to use the deprecated Dart Web UI in which the original Widget.dart library was written...